# Is there a way to downgrade from Win 10 build 15063 to 14393 when it was a new installation?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-installation

We made a big mistake and set up a new Deployment image for the Windows 10 Creators Update (build 15063) in our WDS to deploy the new Windows to our computers.

Now we have about 10 machines with the new Creators Update, but our ERP System doesn't work correctly with this Windows Version, with Windows Version 14393 the ERP System works fine.

Is there a way to downgrade from 15063 to 14393 when the 15063 installation was not an update, but a completely new installation? We don't want to set up the computers from scratch again because of time issues if it's possible.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Download Anniversary update iso from https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/software-download/windows10 & install from the setup.exe or see this http://www.thewindowsclub.com/rollback-uninstall-windows-10-creators-update

Comment: @Biswa unfortunately setup.exe doesn't let me keep my apps & files since i want to install a lower version. I guess There's no way to keep my stuff...

Comment: correct, this is not possible.